# EF Core 7 - query with multiple includes enumerates entities multiple times

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-6.0, ef-core-7.0

We have this [database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S65oa.png)
and a test case where we search for a `Connection` and test the uniqueness of all associated `Departures` by `Id`.

In EF Core 6, everything was correct - we got the correct data (each `Departure` entry once), but after upgrading to EF Core 7 (7.0.0 or 7.0.2), the result now lists some `Departures` multiple times and we end up with the test failing as some Ids are present twice.

The test code:

```
// ...preparing DI
this.lines = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILinesRepository>();
lines.Load(); // heavy task loading the data into memory for about 2 minutes (i know it's not really good but it's not my code...)
var connection = lines.GetConnection(lineNumber, connectionNumber); // filtering the data loaded in previous step
var groups = connection.Departures.GroupBy(d => d.Id); // finding the number of distinct IDs
Assert.Equal(groups.Count(), connection.Departures.Count);
```

`lines.Load(DateTime? forDate = null)`:

```
var date = forDate ?? DateTime.Today;
// ... fetching some other data
_departures = DeparturesSet
     .Include(d => d.TariffStation)
          .ThenInclude(ts => ts.BackwardPlatform)
     .Include(d => d.TariffStation)
          .ThenInclude(ts => ts.ForwardPlatform)
     .Include(d => d.TariffStation)
          .ThenInclude(ts => ts.Station)
     .Include(d => d.Connection)
          .ThenInclude(l => l.Line)
                .ThenInclude(l => l.Validity)
     .Where(d => !d.Connection.Line.ValidTo.HasValue || d.Connection.Line.ValidTo.Value >= date)
     .AsSplitQuery()            
     .ToArray();
// ... fetching some other data
```

`ConnectionEntity? GetConnection(long lineNumber, int connectionNumber)`:

```
_departures?.FirstOrDefault(d =>
            d.Connection.Line.IsValid(DateTime.Now) && d.Connection.Number == connectionNumber && d.Connection.Line.Number == lineNumber)?.Connection;
```

I've tried commenting out different parts in the `_departures` query except for includes of `Connection` and `Line` because without those the test fails with null ref.

The test fails whenever the query contains at least one `.Include(d => d.TariffStation)` (even without the `ThenInclude` part).

It seems that the `TariffStation` which is getting included is also fetching all its `Departures` which are not specified in the entity class nor its mapping.

The configuration of the relation between `TariffStationEntity` and `DepartureEntity` (`b`: `DepartureEntity`):

```
builder.HasOne(b => b.TariffStation)
   .WithMany()
   .HasForeignKey(b => b.TariffStationId)
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```